# What would be the best approach to implement a multi-select combo in SWT/JFace?

Tags: swt, jface

I need to implement a multi-select combobox using SWT/JFace, What would be the best approach?should i go for changing the source code or i should try to extend the combo?

Comment: I think wrapping the SWT List widget could be a solution.

Comment: Do you really want a `Combo` or do you just want something like a `List` where you can select multiple values? EDIT: Just saw your comment. So, just use a `List` then.

Comment: If you look at the restrictions section on the [Combo](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Combo.html) widget, you'll see "This class is not intended to be subclassed by clients".  :(

Comment: @david As an addition: This is true for all [`Control`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html)s except for `Canvas` and `Composite`.

Comment: you may need to look at how org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo is implemented. CCombo has list as widget in the drop down, you can replace it with SWT Table and start customizing the way that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It is not possible to extend a `Combo`</strike> It is possible to extend `Combo` by overriding `checkSubclass()`, however it is highly disapproved of. The alternative is to create a wrapper for it. But that would be too much work.

Extending a `CCombo` is an option, but not a very good idea. Again, too much work for the functionality you need.

**BUT**

1. As [sambi reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374773/sambi-reddy) mentioned, you could use a `TableComboViewer` from [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/snippets.php) (scroll down to "TableCombo").
2. Another convenient solution (my favorite) is to have a [CheckboxTreeViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FCheckboxTreeViewer.html) since you need to implement multi selection and such.

Comment: Note that it is possible to extend `Combo` by overriding `checkSubclass()`, however it is highly disapproved of.

Comment: @GGrec: Yes i am trying to using the TableCombo from Nebula. but i also like your idea about using CheckboxTreeViewer.

Answer (score 2):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gcfe.png)
https://github.com/lawhcd/SWTMultiCheckSelectionCombo

For anyone who is looking for a widget that allows user to select multiple options from a list of check box style options.

It is based on user1438038's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673121/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-a-combodrop-down-in-java-swt) and extended to provide nearly all of the api required of a widget similar to Combo.