# How to add a checkbox in a combo(Drop down) in java swt?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox, combobox, swt

I want to have checkboxes in a combo(Drop down) so that I can select more than one elements of combo at once. Can this be done? If yes, can you please explain or provide any link if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Original poster asked for a drop down list with multi-selection support as an alternative. Custom implementation of `MultiSelectionCombo` can serve this purpose.

---

1. Selected items are displayed in text field:

[Drop down with multi-selection support http://s12.postimg.org/7ee1y6j5n/Multi_Selection_Combo.png](http://s12.postimg.org/7ee1y6j5n/Multi_Selection_Combo.png)

2. Keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed to select multiple items:

[Select multiple items in drop down http://s3.postimg.org/ufkezh99t/Items_selected.png](http://s3.postimg.org/ufkezh99t/Items_selected.png)

3. Get indices of selected items:

[Get selected items http://s11.postimg.org/8n9fa7fb5/Get_selected_items.png](http://s11.postimg.org/8n9fa7fb5/Get_selected_items.png)

---

Implementation and demo of `MultiSelectionCombo`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class MultiSelectionCombo extends Composite {

   Shell    shell               = null;
   List     list                = null;

   Text     txtCurrentSelection = null;

   String[] textItems           = null;
   int[]    currentSelection    = null;

   public MultiSelectionCombo(Composite parent, String[] items, int[] selection, int style) {
      super(parent, style);
      currentSelection = selection;
      textItems = items;
      init();
   }

   private void init() {
      GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
      layout.marginBottom = 0;
      layout.marginTop = 0;
      layout.marginLeft = 0;
      layout.marginRight = 0;
      layout.marginWidth = 0;
      layout.marginHeight = 0;
      setLayout(new GridLayout());
      txtCurrentSelection = new Text(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
      txtCurrentSelection.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

      displayText();

      txtCurrentSelection.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseDown(event);
            initFloatShell();
         }

      });
   }

   private void initFloatShell() {
      Point p = txtCurrentSelection.getParent().toDisplay(txtCurrentSelection.getLocation());
      Point size = txtCurrentSelection.getSize();
      Rectangle shellRect = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y + size.y, size.x, 0);
      shell = new Shell(MultiSelectionCombo.this.getShell(), SWT.NO_TRIM);

      GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
      gl.marginBottom = 2;
      gl.marginTop = 2;
      gl.marginRight = 2;
      gl.marginLeft = 2;
      gl.marginWidth = 0;
      gl.marginHeight = 0;
      shell.setLayout(gl);

      list = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
      for (String value: textItems) {
         list.add(value);
      }

      list.setSelection(currentSelection);

      GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
      list.setLayoutData(gd);

      shell.setSize(shellRect.width, 100);
      shell.setLocation(shellRect.x, shellRect.y);

      list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mouseUp(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseUp(event);
            currentSelection = list.getSelectionIndices();
            if ((event.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == 0) {
               shell.dispose();
               displayText();
            }
         }
      });

      shell.addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {

         public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent arg0) {
            if (shell != null && !shell.isDisposed()) {
               currentSelection = list.getSelectionIndices();
               displayText();
               shell.dispose();
            }
         }
      });
      shell.open();
   }

   private void displayText() {
      if (currentSelection != null && currentSelection.length > 0) {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         for (int i = 0; i < currentSelection.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
               sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(textItems[currentSelection[i]]);
         }
         txtCurrentSelection.setText(sb.toString());
      }
      else {
         txtCurrentSelection.setText("");
      }
   }

   public int[] getSelections() {
      return this.currentSelection;
   }

   // Main method to showcase MultiSelectionCombo
   // (can be removed from productive code)
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Display display = new Display();
      Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
      shell.setText("MultiSelectionCombo Demo");

      // Items and pre-selected items in combo box
      String[] items = new String[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Zeta", "Eta", "Theta", "Iota", "Kappa" };
      int[] selection = new int[] { 0, 2 };

      // Create MultiSelectCombo box
      final MultiSelectionCombo combo = new MultiSelectionCombo(shell, items, selection, SWT.NONE);
      combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
      ((GridData)combo.getLayoutData()).widthHint = 300;

      // Add button to print current selection on console
      Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
      button.setText("What is selected?");
      button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Selected items: " + Arrays.toString(combo.getSelections()));
         }
      });

      shell.pack();
      shell.open();
      while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
         if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
         }
      }
      display.dispose();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7f51.png)
https://github.com/lawhcd/SWTMultiCheckSelectionCombo

For anyone who is looking for a widget that allows user to select multiple options from a list of check box style options.

It is based on user1438038's idea and extended to provide nearly all of the api required of a widget similar to Combo.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the SWT Combo (or CCombo).

The Eclipse Nebula project [TableCombo](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) supports a Table shown as a Combo, so you may be able to use an `SWT.CHECK` style table with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such control in SWT on default. However, you can extend either `Combo` or `CCombo` to implement checkboxes yourself.

A `Table` with `SWT.CHECK` style might be a better option, though:

[image: Table with checkboxes]

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class TableCheckBoxCell {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText("Item " + i);
    }
    table.setSize(100, 100);

    shell.setSize(200, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Source: [Table With CheckBox Cell](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/TableWithCheckBoxCell.htm)

Comment: what if I add SWT.CHECK styling for combo?

Comment: It won't work, combo boxes do not support ``SWT.CHECK`` style.

Comment: Can I make a drop down list instead of combo and have an option to select more than one elements?

Comment: Added another answer with a custom ``MultiSelectionCombo`` that provides a drop down list with multi-selection support.